# BFOs and ‘jobs’ – Java only, no .NET?

Tags: java, content-management-system, documentum

I have started investigating Documentum (I have Developer Edition 6.6) for a task that, probably, will require usage of Documentum’s  Business Object Framework (BOF) objects (TBOs and Aspects) and Documentum’ ‘jobs’. Do I understand correctly that both BOFs and ‘jobs’ can be written on Java and not on .NET? It is important for me because of my project is .NET-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is correct. Documentum is, at its core, a Java based application, and you will be required to write these jobs in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your BOF elements will need to be written in Java.  (Possibly, some PIA approach would work but I haven't tried it and suspect it'd be tough.)

Jobs can be written in any language with varying degrees of integration.  For example, a job (scheduled method) can be pointed towards any executable.  In this case, you wouldn't have deep integration and would need to receive everything via command line.  A java or dmbasic method would have deeper insight.

Comment: "A java or dmbasic method would have deeper insight" - but NOT .Net, correct?

Comment: "In this case, you wouldn't have deep integration and would need to receive everything via command line" - and what such external prigram can do Documentum-specific at all? To use DFS only?

Comment: Re: "NOT .Net" - you're right.  For example, because Java and Docbasic methods are hosted by a server process, they can easily take advantage of connection pooling.  Because executables are short-lived, they cannot.

Comment: An external program could use DFS or DFC to accomplish pretty much anything. It just takes a more deliberate effort to create a connection and relay parameters.  There's likely a small performance hit as well.